# Updating postsharp form 4.x to 5.x

Tags: postsharp

I try to upgrade postsharp 4.0.30319 to 5.

When i try Project - Nuget Packages - Update PostSharp - Update all Packages the following happens:

First a list of installation appears
...
"PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics 5.0.31" was installes succesfully.

then
Install failed. Rolling back...
Fehler beim Update von "PostSharp 4.3.33" auf "PostSharp 5.0.31". Es wurde keine Version von "PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics" gefunden, die mit "PostSharp 5.0.31" kompatibel ist.

So it seems that first an update of the packages is installed, and then afterwards it is said that the package is not found.

I have no clue how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the reported error it looks as if the Diagnostics 5.0.31 package was not available on NuGet. The package is currently available, so this could've been a temporary error.

Please also note that Diagnostics in PostSharp 5.0 is a complete re-write that is not backward compatible with 4.3 version. You can follow a documentation page about the upgrade process from 4.3 to 5.0: http://doc.postsharp.net/logging-upgrade